# Random Word in Dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How might I get a python function to, every time it is called, pick a random five-letter word from the English dictionary?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could this be of any use? https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: It would load an english language from some source, then probably use the `random` library to select a word from that text corpus

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/)'s corpus along with `random.sample`:

```
>>> from nltk import words
>>> import random
>>> print(random.sample(words.words(), 5))
[u'myectopia', u'hinch', u'venation', u'toeboard', u'pennet']
```

**Edit**

To get a random five letter word:

```
>>> five_letter_words = [w for w in words.words() if len(w) == 5]
>>> print(random.choice(five_letter_words))
gaudy
```

Comment: While NLTK requires installation, I think that this is the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have stored all your English words in a file `words.txt`. Then you can read them in like so:

```
myWords = []
with open("words.txt", "r") as inF:
    for line in inF:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "": continue
        myWords.append(line)
```

in order to reduce the list so that only those words of length 5 are left, you can use the filter function:

```
myWordsOf5Chars = list(filter(lambda x : len(x) == 5, myWords))
```

and then, afterwards, you can use

```
from random import choice
print(choice(myWordsOf5Chars))
```

in order to pick a random word from this list and output it.